# How can I attach the correct JSON fetch results to their corresponding container divs?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm trying to display a table of events from a JSON fetch - it mostly works as is, the only thing I'm struggling to figure out is how do I attach the correct events to be listed with their corresponding competition titles.

The result I'm getting right now are wrong as:
the first competition shows all of the fetched competitions' matches,
the second one shows all matches except the first ones',
the third competition shows all of the matches except the first and the seconds'
and so on.

As the below code shows I'm creating a wrapping div and a 'p' for the competition title, and after that I'm attaching the events (esports matches):

```js
function appendData(data) {
  var mainContainer = document.querySelector(".calendar-list");
  for (var i = 0; i < data.competitions.length; i++) {
    mainContainer.innerHTML +=
      `<div><p class="event">` + data.competitions[i].name + `</p></div>`;
    for (var j = 0; j < data.competitions[i].events.length; j++) {
      for (var x of document.querySelectorAll(".calendar-list>div")) {
        x.innerHTML +=
          `<p class="match"><span>` +
          data.competitions[i].events[j].home.name +
          `</span><span>` +
          data.competitions[i].events[j].away.name +
          `</span><span>` +
          data.competitions[i].events[j].cutoffTime.slice(11, 16) +
          `</span></p>`;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the html structure of the list (with 2 competitions and a few events/matches) looks like this (except in reality the events are not sorted correctly):

```html
<div class="calendar-list">
  <div>
    <p class="event">World Cup</p>
    <p class="match">
      <span>Cloud9 White Cloud</span><span>Guild X</span><span>17:00</span>
    </p>
    <p class="match">
      <span>G2 Gozen</span><span>Liquid Brazil</span><span>17:00</span>
    </p>
    <p class="match">
      <span>Cloud9</span><span>Guild X</span><span>17:00</span>
    </p>
    <p class="match">
      <span>G2 Gozen White</span><span>Liquid Brazil</span><span>17:00</span>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p class="event">Champions Tour: Game Changers Championship</p>
    <p class="match">
      <span>Cloud9 White</span><span>Guild X</span><span>17:00</span>
    </p>
    <p class="match">
      <span>G2 Gozen</span><span>Liquid Brazil</span><span>17:00</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I display only the matches that are inside each competition for their list view?

Answer (score -1):

Just use `let` instead `var`. Problem in scope: for `var` scope is global always, but `let` has local scope.

```js
function appendData(data) { 
  // use const is better
  const mainContainer = document.querySelector('.calendar-list');
  // use let in for-loop
  for (let i = 0; i < data.competitions.length; i++) {
    mainContainer.innerHTML += `<div><p class="event">` + data.competitions[i].name + `</p></div>`;
    for (let j = 0; j < data.competitions[i].events.length; j++) {
      for (let x of document.querySelectorAll('.calendar-list>div')) { x.innerHTML += `<p class="match"><span>` + data.competitions[i].events[j].home.name + `</span><span>` + data.competitions[i].events[j].away.name+ `</span><span>` + data.competitions[i].events[j].cutoffTime.slice(11, 16) + `</span></p>`;
      }
    } 

  }
}
```

It should help you.

And possible you have mistake in loop logic. Try something like that:

```js
function appendData(data) { 
  const mainContainer = document.querySelector('.calendar-list');
  
  // create events wrappers and put name
  for (let eventList of data.competitions) {
    // create wrapper for match list
    const wrapperDIV = document.createElement('div');
    
    // create p with name
    const nameP   = document.createElement('p');
    nameP.classList.add('event');
    nameP.innerHTML = eventList.name;
    // put it in wrapper
    wrapperDIV.appendChild(nameP);
    
    // create events
    for (let event in eventList.events) {
      const eventDIV = document.createElement('div');
      eventDIV.innerHTML = `
      <p class="match">
      <span>${event.home.name}</span>
      <span>${event.away.name}</span>
      <span>${event.cutoffTime.slice(11, 16)}</span>
      </p>
      `
      // put it in wrapper
      wrapperDIV.appendChild(eventDIV);
    }
    
    // now put it in DOM
    mainContainer.appendChild(wrapperDIV);
  }
}
```

Comment: nope, sadly the same issue - using "let" didn't change anything.
There is also something wrong with the above rewritten appendData - it doesnt give any output

Comment: the above breaks with ' for (let event in eventList.events)  etc' - if I remove that it works as much to add the event titles, but not the events itself

Comment: investigating it further, the ${event.home.name} format doesn't seem to work in the second loop - although I've tried with event.home.name too, that doesn't work either

Comment: okay, found the problem, your second for loop was with 'in' instead of 'of' - that fixed it